# It is possible to use hundredths of minute in a timer in Xamarin. Forms

Tags: c#, timer, xamarin.forms

I need to measure time at Xamarin. Forms in hundredths of minute, but I can't find any timer that I allow use this unit of measure, the minimum unit of measure I have found is in milliseconds.

```
        var ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);

        Device.StartTimer(ts, () =>
        {
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: minimum unit in this case should be tick( 1/10000 milliseconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 1 second = 1000 milliseconds. So 1/100 of a minute is 600 milliseconds. So you could try to do something like:

```
TimeSpan hundredthOfAMinute = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600);
```

And by the way, `TimeSpan` is a .Net type, so it's not specific to Xamarin or Xamarin Forms.